# What parts of the image tracing process can be handled by classes in the JDK?

Tags: java, image, vector-graphics

I have a study assignment where I need to write a Java program to trace (vectorize) images.

I may only use the JDK 1.5 and up; so, I'll have to implement some algorithms where required.

The program has to pass the following steps:

1. Color reduction (color quantization); [for a *set of colors* or a maximum *number of colors*]
2. Removal of areas [with a given maximum size]
3. Edge detection
4. Simplify segments [minimum is the Douglas-Peucker algorithm]
5. Round segments to curves
6. Output to SVG

I want to make sure that I use JDK APIs wherever possible. My previous research however didn't really turn up a lot of helpful resources. (Most helpful resource thus far is the Sun documentation of the JAI -- Java Advanced Imaging API -- at [this location](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-5413-10/806-5413-10.pdf))

My question is: which of these steps can be handled — or facilitated — by classes in the JDK?

---

Since this is a rather comprehensive question, I'll put up a 250 point bounty once I can.

Comment: Do you have a concrete question?

Comment: "What parts of the image tracing process can be handled by classes in the JDK?" ;) I added it to my post.

Comment: I recommend yo u to begin doing something, and if you find problems, ask a question, but it is very hard to answer to your question without doing all your homework for you.

Comment: You can use a byte array to store the data and write a file with an `OutputStream`. Other than that, I'm afraid there isn't much. What did you expect/what are you hoping to find?

Comment: @Arian I was basically hoping someone who has experience with the JAI (Java Advanced Imaging) library to shed some light on which of the operations to use -- if there are any. Google'ing did not turn up much.

Answer (score 1):

Classes written using the JDK can handle all aspects of the image tracing process (since Java is Turing complete and image tracers exist, they can be implemented in Java - QED). As for your specific areas of inquiry,

> 1) Yes! The JAI includes [quantization](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/ColorQuantizerDescriptor.html) methods.
> 6) Yes! Try the [Batik SVG Toolkit](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/), especially the [SVG Generator](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html).
> 2-5) You're going to have to implement. 4) in particular looks like there are some implementations available but I have not investigated in detail.

Comment: Thanks. I may not include external libraries (only JDK). Hence my question.

Comment: Also -- to clarify -- I wasn't asking whether it's possible to write an Image tracer in Java (that's a given); I was asking whether some parts of that process already have implementations in the JDK or may be facilitated by classes in the JDK (like the JAI library).

Answer (score 1):

> **The Java choice for image processing tool is [JAI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html). There's documentation avaliable and is compatible with the rest of Java tools.**

Do you need to *implement* such image processing tasks and algorithms or just to apply and get their effects? Even you may rather use pure JDK, I insist for being helped out with external libraries. FMHO that will be the best alternative.

I suggest to go for [Open CV](http://opencv.org/), a really complete and stable image processing library. It has now Java support and a good documentation avaliability and you'll find also a compromised [community](http://answers.opencv.org/).

Stuffs like you mentioned:

1. Color reduction (color quantization); [for a set of colors or a maximum number of colors]
2. Removal of areas [with a given maximum size]
3. Edge detection Simplify segments [minimum is the  Douglas-Peucker algorithm]
4. Round segments to curves

Are as easy as use the libraries functions and about SVG I think it can be also performed with it.

Answer (score 1):

> What parts of the image tracing process can be handled by classes in
>   the JDK?

Java can handle all the processes required by your image processing program, no problem. The real question is , do you want to write your own classes or use a 3rd party library ?

Comment: You should mention the required Java classes or platform tools